# UISwitch is not working when we slide over it in IOS 10.2

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have been getting this error that when i slide over my switch its state "On" and "Off" is not working in iOS 10.2 running phones. However when i click on it, The same switch gets it states called correctly. I crosschecked it with a iOS 9.3 running phone. Here both state work correctly both when sliding finger or on click. Is it a minor bug of iOS 10.2 or is it the problem with my code(I don think so, as it work correctly in 9.3)

My code

```
  @IBAction func Switch_clicked(sender: AnyObject)
{
    if switch_btn.on
    {

        print("button on")
        self.EnableTouchID()

    }


    else
    {

        print("button off")
        self.DisableTouchID()


    }

}
```

Note: The main problem is that switch gets slideded on to "ON" or "OFF" without invoking .on or .off states

Comment: Can you check the control event that you have bind with `UISwitch`, check that is it `valueChanged` or not?

Comment: The controls event doesn't get called in IOS 10.2 when sliding my finger.However switch gets its state changed

Comment: UISwitch `Event` type should be `valueChanged` to get invoking .on or .off states.

Comment: @Jeesson_7 What I'm asking is check that Event of `UISwitch` is `valueChanged` or not if it is not `valueChanged` then you need to remove the previous one and set the new one with `valueChanged`.

Comment: Then why is it working in 9.3?

Comment: @Jeesson_7 Previously which event you have register if you have set touch up one then may be it is calling it when you slide its state because of touch up.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Check the `event type` of `UISwitch` for which the `IBAction` method is called. It must be `valueChanged`.

[image]

```
@IBAction func onChangeSwitchState(_ sender: UISwitch)
{
    if sender.isOn
    {
        print("button on")

    }
    else
    {
        print("button off")
    }
}
```